# Swift- Assigning arrays to tableview within collectionviewcell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I'm learning Swift while building an app. Anyways, I'm trying to assign 4 different arrays into 4 different tableview within 4 different collectionviewcells. I was wondering how I will be able to put:

```
var fallQuarter : [String] = ["HELLO", "HELLO"]
var winterQuarter : [String] = ["BYE", "BYE", "BYE"]
var springQuarter : [String] = ["HI", "HI"]
var summerQuarter : [String] = ["OKAY", "OKAY"]
```

these four arrays (for example) to the tableview within collectionviewcell.
Right now, each of the tableview in each collectionviewcell seems to display all 9 items of these 4 arrays. However, I want to assign each array to each tableview within the collectionviewcell. Thanks for your help in advance .

[image: example image]

Here is the main code:

```
import UIKit

    class yearOne: UICollectionViewController {

    let customCellIdentifier = "cellID"

    let quarters = [
        customLabel (title: "Fall Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Winter Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Spring Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Summer Quarter")
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.register(quarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: 
        customCellIdentifier)

        navigationItem.title = "Year One"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        //navigationItem.prompt = "Click the + button to add courses, Swipe left on a course 
        to delete."

    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection 
    section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
        return quarters.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
    indexPath:IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: 
        customCellIdentifier, 
        for: indexPath) as! quarterCell
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        cell.quarters = self.quarters[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
        let destination = SearchPage()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Here is the extension:

```
extension yearOne : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
    UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let width = (view.frame.width - 30)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: 200)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
    UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    } 
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
    UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: 
    UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 10, bottom: 30, right: 10)
    }

}
```

Here is the quarterCell:

```
class quarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    var fallQuarter : [String] = ["HELLO", "HELLO"]
    var winterQuarter : [String] = ["BYE", "BYE", "BYE"]
    var springQuarter : [String] = ["HI", "HI"]
    var summerQuarter : [String] = ["OKAY", "OKAY"]

    let tableView:UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()

    let cellId = "coursesName"

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        switch section {
        case 0:
            return fallQuarter.count
        case 1:
            return winterQuarter.count
        case 2:
            return springQuarter.count
        case 3:
            return summerQuarter.count
        default:
            return 5
        }
    }

    let sectionsArray: [String] = ["fall", "winter", "spring", "summer"]

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
    UITableViewCell {
        let sectionName = sectionsArray[indexPath.section]
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        switch sectionName {
        case "fall":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            let fall = self.fallQuarter[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = fall
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            return cell
        case "winter":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            let winter = self.winterQuarter[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = winter
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            return cell
        case "spring":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            let spring = self.springQuarter[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = spring
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            return cell
        case "summer":
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
            let summer = self.summerQuarter[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = summer
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            return cell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat 
    {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: 
    UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == .delete) {
            // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the 
            tableview)

            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //add class information???
    }

    var quarters: customLabel? {
        didSet {
            guard let quarters = quarters else {return}
            quarterLabel.text = quarters.title
        }
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(tableView)
        setupView()
    }

    func setupView(){

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        contentView.addSubview(quarterLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(addButton)

        quarterLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        quarterLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 
        10).isActive = true
        quarterLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 
        10).isActive = true

        addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: quarterLabel.topAnchor, constant: 
        -5).isActive = true
        addButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 
        -10).isActive = true
        addButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        addButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true

        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 
        35).isActive = true
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 
        5).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 
        -10).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 
        -5).isActive = true

        // each collection view cell (row) = should display xxQuarter Array
        // call indexpath for the collection view and set the tableview to the collection 
        view
        // quarterCell.indexPath

        //if(buttonAction) is cicked from searchPage(), then add the UI label
        //remove course function, add course function

    }

    let quarterLabel : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()//frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: -75, width: 300, height: 50))
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        //label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }()

    let addButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()//frame: CGRect(x: 345, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30))
        button.setImage(UIImage(named: "addicon"), for: .normal)
        button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yearOne.buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you need to in Fall quarter be written all nine items from every array or only the two items from `fallQuarter array`?

Comment: I think the better way to do it is either UITableView or UICollectionView, but using one only, with reusables cell and header view. Much easier to manage. Another style, is using TableView with cells that having 4 labels in UIStackView in it.

Comment: You can use UITableview only with section header and return number of cells in each section according to the number of elements in each of the array.

Comment: One small point - if you have a fixed number of items, just use a `UIStackView`  They are great.

Comment: @ValentinaKonatar I want the Fall Quarter to only display two items from the `fallQuarter array`. But right now, Fall quarter cell is displaying all the items from all 4 arrays

Comment: @PaulJung did you try the solution I posted?

Comment: @ValentinaKonatar I'm getting an error for cellForRowAt saying "Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution for anyone in the future to see...
I made four different customCellIdentifier and registered for four different collectionViewCell

```
class yearOne: UICollectionViewController {

    let customCellIdentifier = "cellID"
    let customCellIdentifier2 = "cellID2"
    let customCellIdentifier3 = "cellID3"
    let customCellIdentifier4 = "cellID4"

    let quarters = [
        customLabel (title: "Fall Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Winter Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Spring Quarter"),
        customLabel (title: "Summer Quarter")
    ]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.collectionView!.register(fallQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier)//
        self.collectionView!.register(winterQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier2)
        self.collectionView!.register(springQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier3)
        self.collectionView!.register(summerQuarterCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier4)

        navigationItem.title = "Year One"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        //navigationItem.prompt = "Click the + button to add courses, Swipe left on a course to delete."

    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return quarters.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if (indexPath.row == 0){
            let cell1 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! fallQuarterCell
            cell1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
            cell1.layer.borderWidth = 2
            cell1.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell1.quarters = self.quarters[0]
            return cell1
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1){
            let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier2, for: indexPath) as! winterQuarterCell
            cell2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
            cell2.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell2.quarters = self.quarters[1]
            return cell2
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 2){
            let cell3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier3, for: indexPath) as! springQuarterCell
            cell3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            cell3.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell3.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell3.quarters = self.quarters[2]
            return cell3
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 3){
            let cell4 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: customCellIdentifier4, for: indexPath) as! summerQuarterCell
            cell4.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
            cell4.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell4.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            cell4.quarters = self.quarters[3]
            return cell4
        }
        else{
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
```

[image: added the string to each data array]

Then I made four different class and created a different array of data in each

`class fallQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

`class winterQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

`class springQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

`class summerQuarterCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource`

Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try with multidimensional array:

```
let data = [["HELLO", "HELLO"], ["BYE", "BYE", "BYE"], ["HI", "HI"], ["OKAY", "OKAY"]]
```

For the number of sections use:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return data.count
}
```

Then, to specify the number of rows in each section use:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return data[section].count
}
```

Then setup your cells:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

}
```

Comment: If I don't add this:     func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }, then Array only returns the first section in the data array, but if I add this then all of the items in data array would display in each tableview in each collectionview cell.